# Injecting Guzzle with Parameters Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, api, rest-api, dependency-injection, guzzle

Writing some REST API bits and going to use Guzzle, which I have used many times before.

The issue I am coming across is, I know Guzzle has to take the configuration via parameters when constructing it, but when using dependency injection to instantiate Guzzle in my model, I can't then set the configuration parameters on it.

Whats the best way to handle this?

Thanks

Comment: https://belvg.com/blog/shortly-about-magento-2-0-web-apis.html & https://github.com/springimport/magento2-api-v1

Answer (score 0):

Magento doesn't provide a centralize way to make api REST call to external services.
I worked with lot of customers, developers always use their own REST implementation using multiple libraries like Guzzle, Curl, Zend...

That's why I recommand you to use this module to industialize your REST API call through Guzzle library: https://github.com/zepgram/module-rest

- Prevent code duplication with a basic implementation in di.xml (only 1 class to create)
- Centralize all your REST web service under the same configuration
- Benefits built-in registry and cache system to ensure and secure performance
- Include a generic logger with a debug mode option to retrieve parameters, request and result
- Declare your request and result as a json serialized or not, avoiding multiple implementation of the serializer